# Find length of specific element of multidimensional array *java*

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d, size

I am trying to find the length of a specific element in a 3D array. I am trying to do this:

---

`if(grid[x][y][0].size<5)`

---

and that I can't seem to figure out the correct way do do this. Thanks!

**Edit:** Unfortunately .length does not work either "length cannot be resolved or is not a field." ALSO, elements are objects.

Some people asked for clarification, I want to know if there are less than 5 objects in the 3rd element of the array.

Thanks!

Comment: `.length` gives the length of an array in Java.

Comment: What is the type of your array? Are elements **strings**?

Comment: If the elements are `int`'s, then you're basically asking how to find the length of a specific `int`.  It's 32 bits.  That's probably not what you're looking for, so you probably need to rethink what you're trying to ask.

Comment: How do you define a "length of int" then?

Comment: Gary, you are still not making much sense. Do you know what 3D array actually is?  Please show us the code the defines `grid`.

Comment: What is the third element of a 3 dimensional array???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use instead of size.

```
grid[x][y].length
```

---

However, you have to remember you are only getting the size of the `[z]` portion of the array.

If you want to get the amount of "cells" in grid you will need to add up all the grid elements.

```
totalsize = grid.length*grid[x].length*grid[x][y].length;
```

Even then you must guarantee that the size of the array at `x y and z` is constant between all the elements.

Remember these are arrays of arrays and they don't have be consistent.

For instance,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] foo = new int[][] {
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4},
    };

    System.out.println(foo.length); //2
    System.out.println(foo[0].length); //3
    System.out.println(foo[1].length); //4
}
```

Dangers...

```
int nir[][] = new int[5][];
nir[0] = new int[5];
nir[1] = new int[3];
System.out.println(nir[0].length); // 5
System.out.println(nir[1].length); // 3
System.out.println(nir[2].length); // Null pointer exception
```

Column lengths differ per row. If you're backing some data by a fixed size 2D array, then provide getters to the fixed values in a wrapper class.

PS.
You can't do `grid[x][y][0].length` because you are accessing a particular element.

Comment: What does it mean "*[0] portion of the array*"?

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression is

```
grid[x][y].length
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this:

```
if(grid[x][y].length < 5){ .... }
```

Comment: The only way that that would work is if the element itself is an array. And if it was, it would be 4 dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of three dimensional array? IF it is String[][][] or int[][][] or something like that you should try `grid[x][y].length` instead size.

Which error it gives?

Comment: If it is `String[][][]` then the correct answer is `grid[x][y][0].length()`, since `length` is a method of the `String` class.  If it is `int[][][]` then the correct answer is 32.  :)

Comment: In the same way that it happens:

int[] test = {1,2,3};
System.out.println("Size: " + test.length);

The size of int array (unidimensional or bidimensional or x-dimensional) is always array.length, not .size.

Comment: You assume an array as element type. This is the only thing the element cannot be, as it would mean that the array was 4 dimensional instead of 3 dimensional...

Comment: So you assume that `[x][y][0]` element is itself an array?

Comment: The [0] gives you the dimension (in this case, the third dimension) you are accessing.

Comment: `grid[...][...][...]` is a **single element** of the array, since `grid` is described as 3-dimensional.

Comment: @HugoSousa Please read my answer for a complete understanding bout multi-dimensional arrays. Kinda weird to comprehend.